# Can we get multiple input as tuples?

Tags: python, input, tuples

I want to get multiple inputs as tuples in a list.
 Example: [(1,2),(1,3),(1,4),(2,5)] 
I wrote this code, it works not bad. But I'm just wondering if there is another way to do this or can we make this code clear?

```
def make_tuple(k):
    tup_list = []
    for i in range(0, len(k)-1, 2):
        tup_list.append((k[i],k[i+1]))
    return tup_list

list1 = list(map(int, input("Enter multiple values: ").split()))
make_tuple(list1)
```

In this way, user should enter the input like; 
 1 2 1 3 1 4 2 5 for getting  [(1,2),(1,3),(1,4),(2,5)]. 
 The actual thing I want is enter the input like; 
 1,2 1,3 1,4 2,5

Answer (score 1):

```
import ast
a = ast.literal_eval(input('some text: '))  

input-(1,2)
output-(1,2)
input-[(1,2)]
output=[(1,2)]
```

This function will accept any input that look like Python literals, such as integers, lists, dictionaries and strings
ast.literal_eval raises an exception if the input isn't a valid Python datatype, so the code won't be executed if it's not.

Comment: The length of the list will be more than 10 tuples. So, it would be challenging for the user to write all characters and numbers.  But thanks for the commend.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `Zip` function to achieve this.You can read more on [Splitting a long tuple into smaller tuples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3947337/splitting-a-long-tuple-into-smaller-tuples)

```py
a = [int(char) for char in input("Enter multiple values: ")]

def zipper(iterable,n):
    args = [iter(iterable)] * n
    return zip(*args)

print(*zipper(a,2))
```

This way if user inputs only 5 digits it can output only 2 tuples of 2 elements each

Comment: I didn't understand how I should enter the input. Could you give an example?

Comment: For the code above the expected input is without space like: 123456.If you want to enter input with a combination of space and comma like 1,2 3,4 5,6: then in above code replace 1st line with `a = [int(char) for char in input("Enter multiple values: ").replace(" ",",").split(",")]`